# int main(void) vs main()

Tags: c, program-entry-point

I am reading `The C Programming Language` and the first program is to print `Hello World` I wrote the code as it shown in the book:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

But I got an error `warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
main()`
. I fixed it by writing the code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is the difference and why should I write it like that?

Comment: C++ clan is at war with the C clan. The fragile truce is maintained by keeping the C++ and C tags separated.

Comment: @Ron I was always wandering why my bedroom looks like after a serious fight. Now I know - as I use both I have to have al least two personalities and they fight when I sleep.

Comment: @melpomene both were asked so many times - it is even not worth to comment - OP did not even use the google

Comment: @melpomene I't about the valid signature of `main` it's an exact duplicate

Comment: @melpomene fixed. You may remove the comment now :D

Comment: @bolov incorrect. `main()` with implicit `int` still returns `int`, and takes no arguments.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala there is an answer on the dupe dealing exactly with that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/2805305

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of C had the concept of a default type.  If a variable is declared without a type, it is assumed to be `int`.  Similarly with functions, if a function is defined without a return type, it is also assumed to return `int`.

More recent versions of C (i.e.  versions less than 25 years old) did away with default types and output a warning in this case.  It's best to explicitly specify the type to avoid ambiguity and keep with more modern C.

Comment: `Older versions of C` you shuld use the term _ancient_ instead